# How to Search for Files in PHP?

Tags: php, filesystems, glob

I have a form in which a user submits a search term and my script will find the matching document names in a MySQL database. We now want to get rid of the database and use only the filesystem for this application.

I want to implement a search function in PHP that behaves similar to the 'LIKE' operator in MySQL. I am familiar with `glob` and have done previous searches on this, but so far haven't come across regex that will give me an equal or similar result as using 'LIKE'.

For example:

```
$search_term = $_POST['search_term'];

$search_results = glob('[uploads/[flags used for search term]]');
foreach($search_results as $result){
?>

<a target='_blank' href="<?php echo $result; ?>">
    <?php echo $result; ?>
</a>

<?php
}
```

**EDIT:**

I just realized I can sync the files using rsync and run a task later that will recurse the newly copied files to get the file names inserted into the database (instead of copying from the original source and cleaning strings).

Comment: Why? Using the filesystem will be a definite performance downgrade.

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) seems pretty clear. Your options are `*` for matching zero or more characters and `?` to match zero or one character. And that's it. No regex here.

Comment: We are are syncing files over a mapped network drive to be displayed on a web page; we've ran into an issue where since the user is using a Mac there are weird things happening to file names that she saves (file names saved with extra bullet point that the user did not add, there are extra spaces added to the file name, etc.). We were using a recursive copy function, but there were syncing issues. We switched to rsync which fixed the issue but now we don't have a way to capture file names.

Comment: @faceymcface you should place a comment under each of the answers given, that way they'd know what's really going on, and/of if one of those solved it or at least helped you after being led in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The basic regex is (sample string "my dog is a yorkshire terrier"):

```
(.*)yorkshire(.*)
```

In PHP this looks like:

```
$pattern = '/(.*)'. $search_term . '(.*)/';
```

Where `(.*)` matches any character (except for line terminators) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

As stated by JBD in comments, `glob()` doesn't support regex so you would have to build a list (array) of names to check against with the regex. As I originally stated in comments, replacing a database lookup with `glob()` is a bad idea on a number of levels.

Comment: The [glob function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) seems to pass the pattern along to the filesystem. I don't think it supports PHP regexes.

Comment: True @JDB, but he could build a list from the glob and loop through the list. I will edit.

Comment: That's fine... but your answer should probably include that. As is... it's very misleading. `glob('/(.*)yorshire(.*)/')` isn't going to return anything.

Comment: Updated the answer @JDB

Comment: Glob do support some kind of simple regular expressions, but only ones supported by `libc`, like simple file path masking.

Comment: @OlegButuzov - I know that there's no official definition for what counts as a "regex" (other than in [formal language theory](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/390teched/regular/reg-lang/definitions.html)) but I think it's a real stretch to include [`glob`](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_426.html) patterns.

Comment: I prefer to use term "mask" in regards of glob, however,  [user contributed docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#88250) refers to this as regexp and describe it as regex with limitations (!not my words!).

Comment: @OlegButuzov Since there are no recognized standards, you can call just about anything you want a regex. However, I disagree with "crayonviolent at phpfreaks dot com", and I do not recognize that semi-anonymous internet post as authoritative. Personally, I'd say that if you can use `.*`, then you're definitely not working with a regex. But yeah... pattern, mask, regex... whatever it is, glob isn't going to be sufficient for what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are no upsides in this solution, glob very limited in case you try to implement search flexible search, however, you can try to use [DirectoryItterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) in order to make a search in directories/files.

I still don't recommend you doing that. What you can do is to make the file with a directory structure, working with strings is much faster than with filesystem, and less dependent then the database.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't generally a good idea. File systems aren't nearly as fast as an indexed database. Also, the simplistic approach of passing along arbitrary user input would allow a hacker to crawl through your entire server (e.g. `glob('../../*')`) and potentially reveal information that could be used to further compromise your system.

You *could* simply select all files you want searched (`glob('*')`) and then apply a regex to that array. Of course, allowing your user to send in an arbitrary regex could [compromise your server](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS).

I think you're better off with your original database approach. You should fix those issues (and the other issues you identified in your comments) rather than making your file system searchable.